# Multi-line string formatting issue in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, string-formatting

I want my label to read like this:

**Name of Activity**

**nn%**

Instead, here's what appears:

**%@**

**%f%**

In addition, I'm getting this warning: **Expression result unused**

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
firstLabel.text = @"%@\n%@%",[self.thisSpec activityOfInterest],focusActivityPercent;
```

`[self.thisSpec activityOfInterest]` returns a string containing the name of an activity, and `focusActivityPercent` is a double.

This is the first time I've tried a multiline label.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify string formatting on a string literal on its own like that. In fact, the code you've shown should be producing a syntax error. You have to use NSString's stringWithFormat: class method:

```
firstLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@%",[self.thisSpec activityOfInterest],focusActivityPercent];
```

Comment: Works great, and it's something I needed to know! Thanks! Only thing now is that it doesn't want to include the "%" (percent symbol), which is part of the intended display. I tried enclosing it in single quotes, and it includes the single quotes, but not the %. What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm getting an "incomplete format specifier" warning. Is it seeing the % as a specifier, even in quotes?

Comment: @TimJones % is an escape character, so you need to add additional % to get it to work. Basically, to have a single percent sign, use %%.